# Programmatically add remove items from listboxes

Tags: powershell, user-interface, listbox

I have three listboxes. Lets call them `listbox 2, 3 and 4`.

`Listbox 2` gets Computers from a button click event. Then I have created `>>` and `<<` buttons to move them between `2` and `3`. Now when I select multiple computers from `3` and click another button called `check` – it should check if the servers that I selected in `3` are pingable or not and move them to `4` if ping is success, while at the same time remove them from `3`. Those that are not-pingable should stay back at `3`.

I keep getting

> List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified.
>   An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.

This is my code:
$buttonCheckStatus_Click={
 $CheckedServerS=$listbox3.SelectedItems
        foreach ($CheckedServer in $CheckedServerS)
        {

```
            If (!(Test-Connection -Cn $CheckedServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet) -eq $true)
            {
                $cSrvr = $CheckedServer
                $listbox4.BeginUpdate()
                foreach($s in $cSrvr)
                {
                    $listbox4.Items.Add($s)--->*****
                }
                $listbox4.EndUpdate()
            }
            elseif(!(Test-Connection -Cn $CheckedServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet) -eq $false)
            {
                [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Server $CServers needs Reboot","msg2")
            }
        }
    }
```

The above works fine and I get the server in listbox 3 that are pingable to listbox 4, BUT: as soon as I add `$listbox3.SelectedItems.remove()` just below `$listbox4.Items.Add($s)` (marked above as `----> *****`) the error starts happening.

After reading through some posts I got that I can't use `foreach`. It is like having the cake and eating it too. But I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide a minimal example which shows what you currently have and your issue (runnable code, so we could run the code locally and observe the exception)? Regarding the exception message you get, it is because an enumerator stops working if the underlying collection is changed. So you can't do a foreach while in the foreach body removing items from the list you're enumerating. An example getting this type of exception: `$arr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,@('item1','item2','item3')); foreach($item in $arr) { $arr.Remove($item) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complaining about that statement because you are still enumerating listbox3.SelectedItems. One way to deal with that could be to record what needs to be deleted in an array, and once you get out of the loop (adding them to listbox4), enumerate that array and remove items from listbox3.

So add

```
$Pingable=@()
```

before you start your loop. Add the server to that array within your loop once they are verified and added to listbox4

```
$Pingable +=$s
```

Once done with the whole loop; enumerate the array and remove them

```
foreach ($p in $Pingable) { $listbox3.Items.remove($p) }
```

In your code:

```
$Pingable=@()
$buttonCheckStatus_Click={ $CheckedServerS=$listbox3.SelectedItems foreach ($CheckedServer in $CheckedServerS) {

            If (!(Test-Connection -Cn $CheckedServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet) -eq $true)
            {
                $cSrvr = $CheckedServer
                $listbox4.BeginUpdate()
                foreach($s in $cSrvr)
                {
                    $listbox4.Items.Add($s)
                    $Pingable +=$s
                }
                $listbox4.EndUpdate()
            }
            elseif(!(Test-Connection -Cn $CheckedServer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet) -eq $false)
            {
                [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Server $CServers needs Reboot","msg2")
            }
        }
    }

foreach ($p in $Pingable) { $listbox3.Items.remove($p) }
```

Comment: Thanks, i am New to PS. can you show me the complete howto ? I am about to jump off my building :( - Thanks Rishi...I mean edit my code and show me

Comment: you there are a god!. I dont have words to thank you Adil...You saved my life. i owe you. And I have become a fan of you and "stackoverflow.com". real champs are here...be around ...we need people like you

Comment: To moderator, Please let me know how i may mark this as answer. the best infact. Everyone else was asking me to redo my code from scratch and avoid foreach but then it would have defeated my purpose... Adil not only solved it but did not "basically" ask me to change anything...that is what I liked most. Kudos Adil...

Comment: You should be seeing 'up' 'down' arrows above and below "0" next to my response. You can click upvote to upvote when you think an answer was useful. under it, there must be a "checkbox". When you click on it; it turns green and the question is marked as "answered"

Comment: i just have 1 reputation here so not able to use the upvote button. it is not allowing me :(  but i have made the tick mark as green...thanks again...